# Like Box not showing in some urls

Tags: php, html, facebook, facebook-likebox

I have a simple yet hard problem here that is driving me nuts ...

Apparantly with no code change what so ever the Facebook and Google+ like boxes show as I want in one section of my site: http://www.nfrases.com/coragem

Yet on the other they just disappear, like on this page: http://www.nfrases.com/coragem/1519

The only difference is that a id_phrase is also suplied instead of only supplying the tag_name in the address that is picked by the php with $_GET and then the mod_rewrite intervenes. The actual address is: http://www.nfrases.com/tag.php?tag_nome=coragem&id_frase=1519

I'm going crazy over here! Someone ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using a relative path for your javascript:

```
<script src="js/scripts.js"></script>
```

So, on `http://www.nfrases.com/coragem`, that would point to:

http://www.nfrases.com/js/scripts.js

But, on `http://www.nfrases.com/coragem/1519`, that would point to:

http://www.nfrases.com/coragem/js/scripts.js

The 2nd URL doesn't exist, obviously. You need to change your script path to:

```
<script src="/js/scripts.js"></script>
```

Same rule applies for some of your images too. Example:

```
<li><a href="#"><img src="images/rss.png" alt="rss"> Acerca</a></li>
<li><a href="#"><img src="images/rss.png" alt="rss"> Sugestões</a></li>
<li><a href="#"><img src="images/rss.png" alt="rss"> Contactos</a></li>
```

Should be:

```
<li><a href="#"><img src="/images/rss.png" alt="rss"> Acerca</a></li>
<li><a href="#"><img src="/images/rss.png" alt="rss"> Sugestões</a></li>
<li><a href="#"><img src="/images/rss.png" alt="rss"> Contactos</a></li>
```